# what's the difference between public/assets and app/assets in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The Rails guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) says

> "Any assets under public will be served as static files by the
>   application or web server when config.serve_static_files is set to
>   true. You should use app/assets for files that must undergo some
>   pre-processing before they are served."

I'm using Rails 4.2.4. There is no public/assets folder. This leaves me wondering a few things:

1. What is meant by "use app/assets for files that must undergo some pre-processing before they are served?"
2. What is meant by pre-processing?
3. How is a static asset different from other assets, and what are the performance benefits of using one pipeline over the other?
4. Do I even need to worry about this if 4.2.4 has no public/assets folder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Assets like javascript/css etc. need to be pre-processed - eg. minified, hashed for cache busting, passed through transpilers (like coffeescript) etc. Such assets should be kept in `app/assets` folder.
2. I believe 1 already answers that.
3. Passing each asset through transpilers/minifiers etc. as described in  1 during production will be very expensive and wasteful - because these assets don't change dynamically we can just do them once during pre-compilation and let static file server or cdn handle their delivery.
4. When you precompile your assets in deployment, the compiled files will be generated into the public/assets folder.

I recommend reading [this article](https://launchschool.com/blog/rails-asset-pipeline-best-practices), which explains asset pipeline in much detail.